# jQuery how to check if a field is empty if so add a class to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i created a field for a zip code on a checkout page and i am trying to have jQuery check if the field is empty. If the field is empty it will add a class of "empty" to a div with an id of "zip", if it is not empty it will have a class of "else" to the div with the id of "zip". Not sure how to do this here is the code i have now.

```js
var value = $.trim($("#billing_zip").val());

 if (value.length > 0) {
     $('#billing_zip').click(function () {
         $('#zip').addClass('empty');
     });
     $('#zip').click(function () {
         $('#zip').addClass('empty');
     });

 }
```

```css
#zip {
    color: #aaa;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 35px;
}
.empty {
    display: inline;
  }
.else {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="billing_zip">Zip</label>
  <input type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);check_address('billing');" class="txtBoxStyle hasPlaceholder" tabindex="10" size="10" value="" id="billing_zip" maxlength="15" name="billing_zip">
  <!--START: req_billing_zip-->
  <img width="12" height="12" alt="" src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif">
  <!--END: req_billing_zip-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="zip">zip</div>
</div>
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63vqkhLy/)
The jQuery is not even working and i only have the code for adding the class "empty".
i hardly know jQuery at all.
Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: You have to run the code in response to events on the input field. If you just put it on your page like this it will only be executed once. I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: You should really just use the placeholder attribute.

Comment: if i use the placeholder attribute all the other jQuery on the page assumes there is text in the field and it screws up other actions on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
     $("#billing_zip").on("focusout keypress click",function(){
            var value = $.trim($("#billing_zip").val());
        alert(value.length);
         if (value.length == 0) { 
                $('#billing_zip').addClass('empty');

                 $('#zip').addClass('empty');
         }
     else
     {
       $('#billing_zip').addClass('else');

                 $('#zip').addClass('else');
     }
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to check value is empty or not on click event.

```
 $('#billing_zip').click(function () {
   var value = $.trim($("#billing_zip").val());
   if(value.length === 0){ 
     $('#zip').addClass('empty');
   }
  });
```

Comment: that did not work it didn't even add the class empty.

Comment: if possible please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: check this fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/1hmdsw03/
Here it apply class "empty" to zip element

Comment: i just added a fiddle

Comment: i dont need it to alert me i just need it to add a class of "empty" if it is empty and a class of "else" if it has text in it

Comment: @Andrew: why you want it on click?

Comment: i put alert so you can understand click event work. it alreday add "empty" class. please make some change in css so you can understand. i wll apply "red" color to class empty . Check now
http://jsfiddle.net/1hmdsw03/

Comment: i need it on click also cause it is a placeholder but i need it to also check if it is empty so that when someone refreshes there checkout page it will not show up again.

Comment: @Andrew: try the solution suggested.

Comment: ok i understand is there a way that when you start typing in the field it adds the class "else" to it so it will dissapear?

Comment: @Andrew : thats what i suggested, Its a keypress event. check it. same you can add on your div if wanted. ( upvote/ mark the answer if it helps )